# Issues with re-indexing process on magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, error, reindex

I have just re-index the data using custom script and its generate this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'abs', ( - i.price), IF( = 'fixed', , ROUND(i.price * ( / 100), 4)))), 0) AS `' at line 1
```

I have tried by making the catalog_product_flat_1 table but still the same issue

Comment: What is the custom script and why are you using it? Does Magento's native reindexer give the same problem?

Comment: Yeah that is also giving the same problem.. @BlueC

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below-mentioned command from Magento root folder

```
cd shell/
php -f indexer.php -- reindex all
```